# Setting ajax data from data attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a better way to set data from a data attribute then

```
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).data('update-url'),
  type: "PUT",
  data: { 
    batch_phase: { 
      "#{$(this).data('attribute')}": new Date().toUTCString() 
    }
  }
});
```

I don't really like `"#{$(this).data('attribute')}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct `data` [sub]object with the key defined using bracket notation:

```
var data = {};
data[$(this).data('attribute')] = new Date().toUTCString();
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).data('update-url'),
  type: "PUT",
  data: { batch_phase: data }
});
```

Comment: You're right - I misread your code. This is why it's always best to *explain* the problem and why your solution helps ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought the onus of explaining the *problem* was on a topic starter :)

Comment: That depends on whether they fully understand it or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[]` around the key to make it evaluate a variable to be an object key.

```js
var aVariable = "me";
var object = {
  [aVariable]: 'weee'
};
console.log(object);
```